# JavaFX WebView Browser

Tags: javafx

```
package webviewbrowser;

import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewBrowser extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new WebViewPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * Create a resizable WebView pane
     */
    public class WebViewPane extends Pane {

        public WebViewPane() {
            VBox.setVgrow(this, Priority.ALWAYS);
            setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

            WebView view = new WebView();
            view.setMinSize(500, 400);
            view.setPrefSize(500, 400);
            final WebEngine eng = view.getEngine();
            eng.load("http://www.google.com");
            final TextField locationField = new TextField("http://www.google.com");
            locationField.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            Button goButton = new Button("Go");
            goButton.setDefaultButton(true);
            EventHandler<ActionEvent> goAction = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    eng.load(locationField.getText().startsWith("http://") ? locationField.getText() :
                            "http://" + locationField.getText());
                }
            };
            goButton.setOnAction(goAction);
            locationField.setOnAction(goAction);
            eng.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    locationField.setText(newValue);
                }
            });
            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            grid.setVgap(5);
            grid.setHgap(5);
            GridPane.setConstraints(locationField, 0, 0, 1, 1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER, Priority.ALWAYS, Priority.SOMETIMES);
            GridPane.setConstraints(goButton,1,0);
            GridPane.setConstraints(view, 0, 1, 2, 1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER, Priority.ALWAYS, Priority.ALWAYS);
            grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(
                    new ColumnConstraints(100, 100, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true),
                    new ColumnConstraints(40, 40, 40, Priority.NEVER, HPos.CENTER, true)
            );
            grid.getChildren().addAll(locationField, goButton, view);
            getChildren().add(grid);
        }

        @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
            List<Node> managed = getManagedChildren();
            double width = getWidth();
            double height = getHeight();
            double top = getInsets().getTop();
            double right = getInsets().getRight();
            double left = getInsets().getLeft();
            double bottom = getInsets().getBottom();
            for (int i = 0; i < managed.size(); i++) {
                Node child = managed.get(i);
                layoutInArea(child, left, top,
                               width - left - right, height - top - bottom,
                               0, Insets.EMPTY, true, true, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code. Can someone help me to add a "Stop" Button to stop loading page, add tab to load multiple page and install Adobe Flash Player to my browser so that I can access Youtube(www.youtube.com).

Thank for helping me.

My am using Netbeans. When i run my application, this is the result.

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebViewBrowser jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebViewBrowser\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebViewBrowser\build\built-jar.properties
compile:
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.2
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\lib\ant-javafx.jar
jfx-deployment:
jar:
run:
Device "Intel(R) HD Graphics Family" (\\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed : 
WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 8.15.10.2302
```

Someone can tell me why?

Comment: I'd suggest splitting your questions up into multiple separate questions in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> add tab to load multiple page

The [willow browser](http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/) is a tabbed JavaFX browser sample project - review that to see how this might be done.

> add a "Stop" Button to stop loading page,

You could try executing `webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().cancel();` in the action handler for a button.  I'm not sure if the WebEngine will respect the cancel request or not.

> install Adobe Flash Player to my browser

You cannot - WebView does not support plugins such as Flash.

> access Youtube

Use YouTube's html5 compliant video playback interface rather than it's flash based interface.

I created some [sample code to play YouTube Videos in a WebView](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1437374).

> WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 8.15.10.2302

Your display driver is out of date and doesn't meet the minimum requirements for using JavaFX - you should update it to a newer version.

Comment: Hi Jewelsea, can you please post some sample application code related to implementation of "willow-browser". Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sample usage code for the willow-browser is in the [willow-browser project source](https://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/source/browse/src/main/java/org/jewelsea/willow/Willow.java).  You can [checkout the complete project source code](https://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/source/checkout) and build it (with maven) and it will create a stand-alone browser application.